# Can i import metric excel using laravel excel?

Tags: excel, laravel, metrics, data-import

I have a biometric excel file as shown in the screenshot. I want to import the excel file using laravel excel. But the format of the excel is different. I tried to import this but its tough to call the data for the particular employee. Is there another way to import a biometric file. Or If i can import this How to do that?

[image]

Comment: You can import any data into Excel, one way or another.  The question is ***how*** are you importing it?  ("Import" is a vague/general term; there are various methods.)  Also, "biometrics data" is also a vague/general term, and it could be stored & organized an infinite number of ways.  Could you [edit] your question to add more specifics & examples?

Comment: Hold on, this isn't even biometric data. I recognize this: I think you mean to say **"call center agent metrics"**. Examples of *biometric data are fingerprint, palm veins, face, DNA, palm print, hand geometry, iris, retina and odour. (I replaced the incorrect tag in your question.)